# User Control Wizard

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, custom-controls

If you add Datagridview to a form, and click on it, a small right arrow appear at the top right. When clicking on it a a menu appears (Choose data source, Edit column, Add Column, etc...)

I am building a custom control based on datagridview. Can someone guide me or tell me where to start of how to add this functionality to my user control?

Comment: You need to build a ControlDesigner - a class which inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner`.  In it you will define some ActionLists to do what you want.

Comment: It took me one hour just to know how to add 'System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner' to my class finding Form.Design should be added by add refrenence and it exist in Framework 4 not in Framework client profile. Then the code sample I found looks like a spell magic written in ancinet language. Thank you for your help, I will stop here :)

Comment: How I can mark Plutonix response as an answer?